# Worm doesn't permit me facebook/yahoo access

Tags: internet-explorer, malware-removal, worm

I've a strange behaviour on my laptop, probably a worm. I can't reach Facebook (there are also other site with blocked access, like yahoo) because every time I write Facebook's URL I'm forwarded to the browser's default page. If I start Internet Explorer with InPrivate mode I can visit Facebook, even if with a limited speed. Nor MalwareBytes, nor Antivir find malicious software. I've tried to install Chrome by Google but setup failed.

What can I do?

Comment: What antivirus are you using?

Comment: If you think it is a worm, try a different AV http://www.kaspersky.co.uk/virusscanner

Comment: What else should be? I'm in your hand :)

Comment: @DaveRook There are impartial industry bulletins which rate anti-virus software. Many free products perform better than paid services, you just don't receive support for the products - as the manpower to provide that support has significant cost for the company. See [VirtusBtn.com](http://www.virusbtn.com/index)

Comment: I mean, it could be other things, but try a different AV just in case! There are many examples of 1 AV detecting a virus where others miss it (regardless of the quality of the AV). Also does this happen with all browsers? Does Firefox let you use Facebook? Or cannot you not install any browser? Either way, you need to download Kaspersky, do a full deep scan (and uninstall Avira first). Not being able to install a browser (Chrome) could suggest more damage than you think

Comment: There is definitely no harm in trying a second anti-virus utility, if you don't pick up anything and still suspect malware.

Comment: What could block me from visiting some sites (facebook, yahoo and other high traffic site) except a malware?

Comment: hosts file, add ons, plug ins

Comment: Possibly a firewall or parental controls. Browsers can have a blacklist of websites also, or require you add the site to a whitelist (such as IE in high security mode).

Comment: Coupled with Amicable's point, you've also stated you can't even install a new browser so I would be more concerned about that !

Comment: I concerned with that too, none have modified the hosts file (maybe a malicious software) or add plugins or somethin else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to visit Facebook by one of it's IP addresses.

Apparently they utilise this range.

- 66.220.144.0 - 66.220.159.255
- 69.63.176.0 - 69.63.191.255
- 204.15.20.0 - 204.15.23.255

They use some, not not necessarily all of these addresses.

- 69.63.176.13
- 69.63.181.15
- 69.63.184.142
- 69.63.187.17
- 69.63.187.18
- 69.63.187.19
- 69.63.181.11
- 69.63.181.12

However if you suspect a worm, you should take steps to remove it. [Avira Free](http://www.avira.com/en/avira-free-antivirus) is currently [scoring the best](http://www.virusbtn.com/vb100/RAP/RAP-quadrant-Aug12-Feb13-1200.jpg).

Download it, install it and schedule a boot time scan.

Comment: I already use Avira, and nothing is found

Comment: @Mariano did you schedule the scan to run at boot time, restart your computer and allow it to scan?
Or did you just run it manually through the application by clicking "Scan Now" or what ever it says once you'd logged in. It does make a difference.

Comment: Only run "Scan now". I will try this way. Thanks